# Error invalid control sequence "a href=\”%s\”

Tags: wordpress, gettext, poedit

I am translating a WordPress theme Magnovus using the default .po file in poEditor 1.6.3 on OSX Mavericks (free version). I got the following errors even when I copied the text over to the translation:

```
error invalid control sequence
```

the string I am translating is

```
You must be <a href=\"%s\">logged in</a> to post a comment.
```

whether I copy it or translate it, I keep on getting this error.

I think the quotes are escaped properly here. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Poedit 1.6.3 occurring for some (but curiously, not all) users on OS X Mavericks. It is related to OS X's Smart Quotes feature, which is on by default since 10.9.

It will be fixed in Poedit 1.6.4 and you can download a fixed build of 1.6.3 from http://www.poedit.net/dl/Poedit-1.6.3b.zip. You will need to manually fix the already-broken invalid translation to use `\"` (i.e. the "dumb quote"), but it won't happen again with 1.6.3b+.

(By the way: http://poedit.net/support.php)

Comment: I have noticed that using poEdit on a Mac that the normal straight speach marks had been swapped with right slanting speach marks. When I swapped them back, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Testing with poEdit 1.6.4 (and MacOSX 10.9.2), these errors of invalid control sequence continue to occur randomly (after fuzzy procedure). The place of errors indicated by red lines in screen table is not good. The only way to repair is to used a text editor and replace \” by \" !
Question : is a way to stop automatic fuzzy suggestion ?
M.

Answer (score -1):

You should use: `%s`, not `\"%s\"`.

Comment: That does get rid of the error, but will %s without "" still load the url properly and will the url work properly? I will need to  see..

Comment: Also ``Logged in as <a href=\”%1$s\”>%2$s</a>. <a href=\”%3$s\” title=\”Log out of this account\”>Log out?</a>`` keeps on reverting to the escaped quotes even after I remove the backslashes and quotes..

Comment: Hmm never mind. In original text quotes and backslashes came back but for translation I could remove them and get it all validated.

Comment: Sorry, but that's a really really *really* bad advice, to create invalid markup.

Comment: Invalid HTML yes. I was talking making poEditor validate it. But with the new fix I keep it valid in the editor and in the browser :-)